# Django template difference between {{ and {% with certain datas

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

```
<script>
    _UserGroup = "{{user.groups.all.0}}"
    console.log(_UserGroup) // prints "Admin"
</script>
{% if user.groups.all.0 == "Admin" %}
    Hello admin // never appears, i assume ^ this fails
{% endif %}
```

I dont understand why the JS section works as expected, but the {% %} section always fails

Any pointers would be appreciated, cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Its because user.groups.all.0 is not string, but is Group object. So if you compare it to string then comparison fails. You should probably change it to

```
{% if user.groups.all.0.name == "Admin" %}

{% endif %}
```

And it does not fail (or raise error) when you print out {{ user.groups.all.0 }} because when you do something like this, then Class's or object's unicode method kicks in and prints out its name as string.